# How to use vector and struct?

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, struct

I need to count letters from the string, sort them by count and `cout` results. For this purpose I'm trying to use `vector` and `struct`. Here is part of my code, but it's not working, because I don't know how to implement something:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct int_pair{
     int key;
     int value;
};  

bool sort_by_value(int_pair left, int_pair right){
    return left.value < right.value;
}

int main() {    
    string characters = "aasa asdfs dfh f ukjyhkh k wse f sdf sdfsdf";    
    vector<int_pair> most_frequent;     

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i <= characters.length(); i++) {
        int int_char = (int)characters[i];
        most_frequent[int_char]++; <-- I want to do something like this, but it's not working 
    }

    sort(most_frequent.begin(), most_frequent.end(), sort_by_value);

    for (vector<int_pair>::iterator it = most_frequent.begin(); it != most_frequent.end(); ++it) <-- is this call correct?
        cout << " " << it->key << ":" << it->value << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

At this code I have 2 parts that I don't know how to deal:

```
most_frequent[int_char]++; <-- I want to do something like this, but it's not working
```

and

```
for (vector<int_pair>::iterator it = most_frequent.begin(); it != most_frequent.end(); ++it) <-- is this call correct?
```

Maybe you can see any other mistakes and potential issues at this code.

Comment: Is this an exercise in using vector? because a map or hashmap is probably a better fit for small strings.

Comment: @PeteKirkham no, it's not. it's my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
most_frequent[int_char].key = int_char;
most_frequent[int_char].value++;
```

Yes, it sets the `key` many times, even though it doesn't need to.

Comment: I updated this line `most_frequent[int_char]++;` with your code and now got: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @viakondratiuk This is because your vector is empty. Accessing elements which don't exist in a vector is forbidden (in contrast to a map) You have to fill the vector with 256 values at the beginning (pass `256` to the constructor of `vector`).

Comment: @viakondratiuk: `vector <int_pair> most_frequent(256);`

Comment: Yes, it's working. But using this approach I'm getting a lot of 0 values. How I can avoid it?

Comment: `if (it.value != 0) print value; else do nothing`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, I understand this. I'm talking about approach. This vector allocates unused memory. It's not good.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I think other solutions already provided does that for you. It would involve either using something other than vector, or spending time searching for `key == int_char` and remembering the location and updating that location.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a std::map to determine the frequency of each letter, then copy that into a multimap while reversing the key and value to get them in order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T, class U>
std::pair<U,T> flip_pair(const std::pair<T,U>& p) {
  return std::make_pair(p.second,p.first);
}

int main(){
  std::string characters = "zxcvopqiuweriuzxchajksdui";
  std::map<char,int> freq;
  std::multimap<int,char> rev_freq;

  // Calculate the frequency of each letter.
  for(char c: characters){
    freq[c]++;
  }

  // Copy the results into a multimap with the key and value flipped 
  std::transform(std::begin(freq), std::end(freq), 
                 std::inserter(rev_freq, rev_freq.begin()), 
                 flip_pair<char,int>);

  // Print out the results in order.
  for(std::pair<int,char> p : rev_freq){
    std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the container with the key (`vector` is indexed with an integer, which is "the key" in your case), you don't have to store the key in the value field of the container again.

So you don't need your `struct` since you only need the value field and can can store the number of occurrences directly in the vector.

The idea is to fill the vector with 256 integers in the beginning, all initialized to zero. Then, use the vector index as your "key" (character code) to access the elements (number of occurrences).

This will result in a code similar to this:

```
// initialize with 256 entries, one for each character:
vector<int> counts(256);

for (string::size_type i = 0; i <= characters.length(); i++) {
    // for each occurrence of a character, increase the value in the vector:
    int int_char = (int)characters[i];
    counts[int_char]++;  
}
```

Once filling of the vector is done, you can find the maximum value (not only the value but also the key where it is stored) using the [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm:

```
vector<int>::iterator most_frequent =
        std::max_element(counts.begin(), counts.end());

// getting the character (index within the container, "key"):
std::cout << (char)(most_frequent - counts.begin());

// the number of occurrences ("value"):
std::cout << (*most_frequent);
```

Here is your example with the changes (only printing the most frequent character, here it is the space so you don't see it): http://ideone.com/94GfZz

You *can* sort this vector, however, you will loose the key of course, since the elements will move and change their indices. There is a nice trick to process statistics like that: Use a *reversed (multi)map* (key, value reversed):

```
multimap<int,int> keyForOccurrence;
for (vector<int>::iterator i = counts.begin(); i != counts.end(); ++i) {
    int occurrences = *i;
    int character = i - counts.begin();
    keyForOccurrence.insert(std::pair<int,int>(occurrences, character));
}
```

Updated code: http://ideone.com/Ub5rnL

The last thing you should now sort out by yourself is how to access and process the data within this map. The fancy thing about this *reversed map* is that it is now automatically sorted by occurrence, since maps are sorted by key.

Comment: I need count of all letters, not only the most frequent one.

Comment: The vector contains all of them.

Comment: @viakondratiuk: the code by leemes should be a good starting point to count all the letters. Surely you don't want him to do all your homework for you?

Comment: @leemes Is there any other approach for this task. I have a lot of 0 values at vector and I think it's an overhead.

Comment: This will occupy 1KB. I doubt that this will be a problem. You can restrict to ASCII characters and only use 128 entries (but please check each character for `<128` if you decide to do so and implement a case for characters beyond ASCII, otherwise your program crashes). A data structure like `map` is clearly more expensive.

Comment: @leemes because map sort it's values?

Comment: @viakondratiuk map is usually implemented as a tree, so it will need a lot of extra pointers to keep track of the tree structure. A vector only needs a single block of memory for storing the elements plus a small amount of extra space for keeping track of the size and capacity of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I find more natural to use a **`std::map`** container to store each character occurrences. The character is map's *key*, its occurrence count is map's *value*.
It's easy to scan the source string and build this map using `std::map::operator[]`, and `++` to increase the occurrence count.

Then, you can build a second map from the above map, with key and value *inverted*: so this map will be sorted by *occurrences*, and then you can print this second map.
Note that you have to use a `std::multimap` as this second map, since its keys (i.e. the occurrences) can be repeated.

Sample code follows (I tested it with VS2010 SP1/VC10):

```
#include <stddef.h>     // for size_t
#include <algorithm>    // for std::transform
#include <functional>   // for std::greater
#include <iostream>     // for std::cout
#include <iterator>     // for std::inserter
#include <map>          // for std::map, std::multimap
#include <ostream>      // for std::endl
#include <string>       // for std::string
#include <utility>      // for std::pair
using namespace std;

int main() 
{    
    string str = "aasa asdfs dfh f ukjyhkh k wse f sdf sdfsdf";    

    // Build the occurrences map (char -> occurrences)
    map<char, size_t> freq;     
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        freq[ str[i] ]++;

    // Build a new map from previous map with inverted <key, value> pairs,
    // so this new map will be sorted by old map's value (i.e. char's
    // occurrences), which is new map's key. 
    // Use the std::greater comparator to sort in descending order.
    multimap<size_t, char, greater<size_t>> sorted_freq; 
    transform(
        freq.begin(), freq.end(),                       // source 
        inserter(sorted_freq, sorted_freq.begin()),     // destination
        [](const pair<char, size_t>& p)                 // invert key<->value
        { 
            return pair<size_t, char>(p.second, p.first); 
        }
    );

    // Print results    
    for (auto it = sorted_freq.begin(); it != sorted_freq.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->second << ": " << it->first << endl;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
>  : 9
> s: 7
> f: 7
> d: 5
> a: 4
> k: 3
> h: 3
> u: 1
> w: 1
> y: 1
> j: 1
> e: 1
> ```

If you don't want to print the space character occurrences, you can easily filter that out.

Note that using `std::map`/`std::multimap` will also scale up better than `std::vector` for non-ASCII characters, e.g. if you use Unicode UTF-32 (since Unicode characters are much more than just 256).